# В чім різниця між «значущість» і «значимість»?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Прочитав статтю [статистична значущість](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%D1%89%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) й її обговорення, але все одно не доберу: чим же відрізняються *значущість* і *значимість*?

---

**Обговорення**

> Може, не «значущість», а «значимість»? Бо «значущість» — це те, що надає сенсу, а «значимість» — це важливість.
>
> ---
>
> [**VodoRiz**](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87:VodoRiz)  Я теж підтримую «значимість». Крім того, є така [стаття](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/5.php).
>
> > Чому дедалі рідше вживають у нас слово значимий?
> >
> > У радянські часи витиснення української мови з багатьох сфер публічного спілкування призвело, писав академік [Іван Дзюба](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B0_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), до нехтування її функціональних можливостей, до завмирання багатьох природних форм вираження, на зміну яким за умов потужного тиску російщення приходили форми спотворені, аж до так званого суржику. З другого боку, втрата природності й краси, засилля кальок з російської та суржику позбавляють нашу мову унікальності, небезпечно зменшують її конкурентоздатність у публічному й приватному мовленні.
> >
> > Тому утворення із «запозиченим суфіксом — *им* (*-ий*) — *значимий, любимий* і таке інше — сприймаються нині як порушення граматичної норми. Відчуття системних звʼязків у мові сприяло поширенню інших форм з таким самим значенням: *значущий, улюблений*. І закономірно надають перевагу, скажімо, словосполученням *значущий результат* (а не *значимий результат*), *значуща подія, улюблена книжка* (а не *любима книжка*), *улюблений кіноактор, улюблена справа* тощо.

Comment: Там до обговіру також приєднався наш знайомий @Sasha з ланками СУМ-20 з висновком тотожності. Сам я [зауважу](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/220.htm), шчо те саме джерело вказує: *значимый* передається як *значущий* (не *значимий*);

Answer (score 1):

Згідно до [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53399/25602.html) та [Онлайнкорректора](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%D1%89%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/) - ці два слова є синонімами та позначають щось важливе, однак бажано вживати слово "значущість", так як "значимість" - калька з російської.